# Making Google Maps API Local Project

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am just getting started with the Google Maps API. I am building a small GIS program. I am trying to get my map to appear in a local HTML document. The Google Maps API documentation does not seem to address this issue. I copied the code from the Google Maps API page. I have created an API key and put it in the right place in the code. Is it possible to make a local HTML document that will open the API?

Code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you created an api key?

Comment: I have and I put it in the correct spot.

Comment: I seem to remember an issue with keys an file:/// URLs.  I believe for the present time, you can use the API on a local filesystem without a key.  Related issue in the issue tracker [Issue 9991: Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError when loading from file://](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9991)

Comment: An API key without restrictions should work with local HTML file. Can you specify the error message that you are facing?

Comment: There is no specific error message. The map simply will not populate once I open the document in the browser.